# Reload variables every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Okay here's the problem.
I want to have 6 realtime variables in php (now they are like Divs). The method I use works fine but it's awful (I know). I need better solution.

Now I load 6 diffrent files like this:

```
<script>
function loadText() {
$.ajax({
    url: ("variable1.php"),
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#variable1").html(data);
    }
});
} setInterval(loadText, 60000);
</script>

<div id="variable1"></div>
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Turn them into a single handler script, return a JSON list like `{"#variable1": 123, …}` so you can use a single request, and update all divs easily (per `.each()` or whatnot).

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to want to do a `setInterval()`?

```
setInterval(function(){loadText();}, 10000);
```

Or, if you want it to run only after successfully completing the call, you can set it up in your `.ajax().success()` callback:

```
function loadText(){
    var text = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "variable1.php",
        async: false
    }).success(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){loadText();}, 10000);
    }).responseText;

    $('#variable1').html(text);
}
```

Or use `.ajax().complete()` if you want it to run regardless of result:

```
function loadText(){
    var text = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "variable1.php",
        async: false
    }).complete(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){loadText();}, 10000);
    }).responseText;

    $('#variable1').html(text);
}
```

Here is a demonstration of the two. Note, the success works only once because jsfiddle is returning a 404 error on the ajax call.

http://jsfiddle.net/YXMPn/

Answer (score 0):

You can always have a function you set to run however often you want that has this... It's a much shorter way... If this is what you mean...

```
$("#variable1").load("variable1.php");
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass this var to php after every reload?

Comment: What it does is it loads whatever is in variable1.php into the variable1 div, just like your code you had. Give that a try and see if it works out...

Comment: You would have to put that code into the loadText() function

Comment: The code you had before was more for if you wanted to submit an html form in the background without reloading or leaving the page. But it does the same thing

Comment: @А.Е. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: I had an html table and I want to load 6 numbers in it. It will be best if these numbers are variables... So I'm not sure if im understandable - my english is not so solid.

Comment: I want my variables at the table to be real-time in most efficient & easy way

Comment: @А.Е. Are the numbers always the same, or dynamic?

Comment: Are they set in variable1.php?

Comment: I think it would work, because the code I gave you should do the same thing.